# How to display all items from Firestore in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, svelte, sveltekit

Im trying to make a To-do app. I can get all the information from firebase in the console, however the only item I can get to display in the ui is the last one. How can i display all of them?

```
let msg 
let textinput
async function f() {
  try {
const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
  name: textinput,
});
console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
} catch (e) {
console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
}}
onMount(async () => {
  
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
// doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
msg = doc.data().name
console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
});
```

```
<h1>
  this is for datebase
</h1>
<input type="text" bind:value={textinput}>
<p>{msg}</p>
```

[ui and the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnqnO.png)
[console_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Agp.png)

I tried {#each querySnaphot as doc}, but querySnapshot is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array. querySnapshot.docs is an array of query results (docs).

```js
{#each querySnaphot.docs as doc}
  <li>{doc.id} => {doc.data().name}</li>
{/each}
```

or

```js
{#each querySnaphot.docs as doc}
  {@const {name} = doc.data()}
  <li>{doc.id} => {name}</li>
{/each}
```

Bonus looping:
If you have an object you can loop:`{#each Object.keys(obj) as key}`
or: `{#each Object.entries(obj) as [key, value]}`

**Update querySnapshot:**

```js
const getQuerySnapshot = async () => {
  return await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
}

let promise = getQuerySnapshot ();
```

The getQuerySnapshot arrow function returns a promise. More [here](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks).
To resolve the promise you can:

```js
{#await promise then guerySnapshot}
  {#each guerySnapshot.docs as doc}
    <li>{doc.id} => {doc.data().name}</li>
  {/each}
{/await}
```

Comment: Thank you, but 'querySnaphot is not defined'. How do I define it outside the function. Sorry if it's a stupid question!

Comment: I get an error: {#each} only iterates over array-like objects. Thank you for your responses!

Comment: Yes. We need the docs array of the guerySnapshot

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [sveltefire](https://github.com/codediodeio/sveltefire) as it avoids a lot of the redundant boilerplate around using firebase and really cleans up svlete code.

You can easily use sveltefire realtime components which automagically get data and subscribe to realtime changes making your data reactive right out of the box

```html
<script>
  import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
  import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
  import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
  import {FirebaseApp, User, Collection} from 'sveltefire'

  // Initialize Firebase...
  const app = initializeApp()
  const firestore = getFirestore(app);
  const auth = getAuth(app);
  
</script>

<FirebaseApp {auth} {firestore}>
  <User let:user>
    Hello {user.uid}
    <div slot="signedOut">You are signed out</div>
  </User>
  <Collection ref="posts" let:data let:count>
    <p>Fetched {count} documents</p>
    {#each data as post}
      {post.id}
      {post.ref.path}
      {post.content}
    {/each}
  </Collection>

</FirebaseApp>
```

It is however useful to learn how firestore works in the first place, but this is a really fun and fast way to work with firebase and svelte